# I have a problem in Flutter with settings.gradle in android folder

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

i can't run my app in Flutter and the error message is this:

```
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
```

I follow this discussion (https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2599) in which they say that the following lines of code must be added in settings.gradle file:

```
def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

But this solution has not served me. Someone knows how can i resolve it?

Comment: Modules `:firebase_auth_web` & `:firebase_core_web` are missing... whatever they may be good for.

Comment: Just ignore the warnings. I also get same errors but it doesn't breaks something.